# How to disable Standard Login Tab from GitLab home Page

Tags: gitlab

I am using `GitLab Community Edition Version - 11.3.4 (30f019d).`

I have integrated our Gitlab with Atlassian Crowd, Centralized login is working perfectly, now I am looking for a way to disable Standard Login tab from GitLab home Page. Since we have already granted GitLab Admin permission to my Crowd-AD account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team, For the same, i have disabled the below settings, Post that i can able to see only my Crowd login Section. Under **Admin--> Settings--> General--> Sign-in restrictions**

[image]